# Multiple ATI Graphics Cards

Tags: 10.04, multiple-monitors, ati

I have a triple monitor setup on Nvidia currently, but after having a number of [difficulties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84765/triple-monitor-setup-with-nvidia-and-compiz) with the Nvidia drivers, I'm thinking about jumping ship to AMD graphics cards with Eyefinity.

I would like the possibility to switch to a quad monitor setup down the road, assuming that the ATI drivers work reasonably after a few days of testing. Since many of the graphics cards require special "active" display converters to convert DisplayPort to DVI, I was wondering if it would be easier to install two lower end graphics cards in my system instead of getting a high end card that has 5/6 DisplayPort connectors. Currently I have 2 HDMI monitors, and one DVI monitor.

I don't need anything fancy in terms of performance; just the ability to run 3 (possibly 4) monitors at 1920x1080 w/ compiz enabled.

Is it possible to have multiple AMD/ATI video cards on an Ubuntu machine?

**Update 2011-15-12:** I have installed a single Radeon HD 6770 with 5 mini display port connectors, so I no longer have a need for multiple graphics cards.

Comment: may be not. see [Triple monitor setup with an ATI Radeon 4200?][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22676/triple-monitor-setup-with-an-ati-radeon-4200

Comment: @jahid65 In that question, the OP only has a single graphics card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two ATI radeon cards on 10.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96753/two-ati-radeon-cards-on-10-04)

Answer (score 1):

Catalyst is available for Linux (http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) so multiple AMD cards won't be a problem I guess.

Comment: How does the availability of Catalyst indicate that multiple graphics cards would not be an issue?

Comment: AMD cards which support Crossfire really depend on the motherboard not on a specific OS and it exists in the hardware level,using it shouldn't be a problem as long as the proprietary drivers are available.

Comment: My motherboard lists CrossFireX as a supported technology. I assume I wouldn't be using CrossFire in my scenario though, right?

Comment: You said "Multiple ATI Graphics Cards", so if you want to install two or more GPUs on a machine you'd require CrossFire (AMD) or SLI (Nvidia).

Comment: I don't think this is the case, because I was able to use two non-SLI Nvidia graphics cards at the same.