# Triple Monitor Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, monitor

I have just installed my first ever Ubuntu! The first major problem is that my second graphics card is not registering.

I have 2 x Radeon HD 6800's connected with a crossfire attatchment. The triple monitors work fine in Windows 7, but not Ubuntu.

I have followed tutorials to install AMD drivers and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably edit to add what tutorial you were using.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ships with Unity, which is dependent on Compiz, which is apparently incapable of handling more than one graphics card at this time.

What worked for me was to completely rip out Unity, Compiz, and lightdm, and then install KDE. Alternately, just install kubuntu (which is just Ubuntu with KDE, a really great desktop environment that's been in development since the '90s, rather than Unity.) This done, you will need to install the 3D card drivers.

At this time, the process of massaging the drivers to do what you want is not intuitive and can be exceedingly difficult. (It is with nVidia, at least, which is puzzling since it works with zero effort in Windows.) You may have to be somewhat tenacious.